# Why I am not able to handle the password field using selenium web driver in new gmail login page?

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium web driver, I am writing script to login in to the gmail below is the test script that I created.

public class gmailEmail {

```
public void login() {
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElementById("Email").sendKeys("XXXXX@gmail.com");
    driver.findElementByName("signIn").click();
    driver.findElementById("Passwd").sendKeys("XXXX");
    //driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='Passwd']").sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='signIn']").click();     
}
```

When I run this the error is triggering at "driver.findElementById("Passwd")" following error message is displaying

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}
(Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.112)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 40 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'Rameshs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=/var/folders/vx/07vnt7mn2jx4fpm983_tq6gm0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.S1jNgs}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=49.0.2623.112, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: f5790b0589eb054c4e11283c80b82f0e
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=Passwd}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
at MobilousLogin.gmailEmail.login(gmailEmail.java:15)
at MobilousLogin.Registration.main(Registration.java:10)
```

If I debug by inserting a breakpoint at "driver.findElementById("Passwd")" then the whole script is working fine.

Can some one please help me out in understanding what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Alternatively, use a proper API for Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it isn't able to identify the element that means by the time selenium has executed the command to enter password, the element wasn't loaded or not visible in the UI.

You may want to use `ImplicitWait` or `ExplicitWaits`. You can read about them [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

You can try `ExplicitWait` to wait for the `Passwd` element:

```
public void login() {
ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
driver.findElementById("Email").sendKeys("XXXXX@gmail.com");
driver.findElementByName("signIn").click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(""What ever");
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='signIn']").click();     
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it is absolutely working fine, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code:

```
public void login() {
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.findElementById("Email").sendKeys("XXXXX@gmail.com");
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='signIn']").click(); 
   driver.findElementById("Passwd").sendKeys("XXXX");    
   driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='signIn']").click();     
}
```

Add chrome driver capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Try it once.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().impliciltyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("email-display").sendKeys("XXXXX@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("next"").click();
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='signIn']").click();
```